# Activar radio al ser true el checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero activar un `radio` al momento de que mi `input checkbox` sea true, con el código que tengo me funciona bien pero una sola vez, al momento de darle otra vez no.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) { 

  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){

  var inputcheck = $(this);

  var checked = $("input[type='radio']");

  if (inputcheck.prop("checked") == true ){

  $(checked).attr('checked', true);

  } else{

  $(checked).attr('checked', false);

} }); })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muesta el html que tienes para que puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es usar el selector `$()` constantemente sobre un elemento que ya buscaste como el caso del inputcheck que lo igualas a `$(this)` por ello limpie un poco mas el código usando ids para los elementos. También cambie la lógica de algunas partes tomando en cuenta la documentación de  [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) .

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#chk").click(function(event) {

    var inputcheck = this;
    var radio= $("#rad");
    
    if (inputcheck.checked) {
    
      radio.prop("checked", true);

    } else {

      radio.prop("checked", false);

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<input id="rad" type="radio" />
```

Comment: Solucionado, gracias! era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un input radio y un checkbox podría ser algo así, entiendo que cuando el checkbox este seleccionado se active el radio y cuando el radio se desactive, este ejemplo puede funcionar este es el html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<input  type="radio" id="radio" disabled>
```

y el javascript

```
$(document)
  .ready(function(){
    $checkbox = $('#checkbox');
    $radio = $('#radio');
    $checkbox.click(function(event){
      var isChecked = event.target.checked;
      if(isChecked){
        $radio.removeAttr('disabled')
      } else {
        $radio.attr('disabled', true)
      }
   })
 })
```